# pass variable from html to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jplayer

```
<%= semantic_form_for :.........  do |f| %>
<%= f.inputs do%>
    <%= pluralize @size, 'Profitable Routes to test'%>
    <p>User id: <%= @id %><p>
    ....

<title> audio player</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <link href="/skin/pink.flag/jplayer.pink.flag.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var u_id = document.getElementById('id')
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ......
                ......
                ......
                .......
        });
    });
        //]]>
    </script>
```

I want to pass the `User id` to javascript, i'm trying to do it with this: `var u_id = document.getElementById('id')` but it says that u_id is null, who can i pass it? Thanks!

Comment: `document.getElementById('id')` will give you the DOM element that has the ID **id**, not the actual element ID

Comment: In the event the script is going to be properly separated into a file and referenced in a script tag within the header, write your required data either into a hidden field or into an elements data attribute. That way you can use just the script to access what you need instead of hacky inline-script. If the hidden field is for example has an id of  "userId" you can then do something similar to `$("#userId").val()` to get the user id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write the variable directly in the JavaScript code:

`var u_id = <%= @id %>;`

Actually when you use `document.getElementById()` in JavaScript you get a DOM element. And not the variable `@id`. The variable `@id` doesn't event exist for JavaScript.

#### Why?

I guess you're using Rails. `@id` is a Rails variable. Rails compiles the templates (on the server) before sending the final html page to the user. It means it replaces all the `<% %>` by the results of each block which are plain text.

The JavaScript is then run on the client browser. It's not aware of Rails.

When you do `var u_id = <%= @id %>;` Rails compiles it in something like `var u_id = 198297;` which is send to the client browser. Then JavaScript is happy, the variable is correctly set.

Comment: Not sure about the exact syntax but would using `<input type="hidden" id="userId" value=@id/>` in the page and `var userId =$("#userId").val()` in the script file not work too and keep the layers separated? I'm assuming this for a flexible solution where the script might not be embedded in the page but instead is in a separate file.

Comment: Should work. But  you can as well use the JavaScript global scope, just define the variable in this page with `<script>var u_id = <%= @id %>;</script>` and use the `u_id` variable everywhere else in JavaScript, even separate files. I wouldn't add an html field just for this purpose.

Comment: @Nope imho your comment is answer worthy... I'd give you a +1. I'm maintaining a prog and due to security settings I'm not allowed to execute in-age scripts. Your suggestion works for me.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('id')` is the element, not its value. You should use something similar to

```
id = document.getElementById('id').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

u_id is the dom element . you should select a attr of this element

```
u_id.value
```

or

```
u_id.innerHTML
```

in jquery :

```
u_id.val()
u_id.html()
```

Comment: That's not going to help if `u_id` is `undefined` because there's no element with an `id` of 'id'; trying to access a property of it would throw an error.